# Debug error when calling task::spawn_root_and_wait in tbb

Tags: c++, vector, tbb

When I run this code for n > 11 I get a debug error saying that abort() has been called. Using the visual studio debugger I found that it was on the task::spawn_root_and_wait(test); line of the code. I have no idea why it is doing this. When I ran the code using an array instead of a vector it ran fine but I was getting concurrency errors. Any advice?

```
   vector<int> p;
class PartTask: public task
{
public:

    const int n;
    int* sum;


    PartTask(int n_, int* sum_) : n(n_), sum(sum_) {}

    task* execute()
    {

        int a, b;
        int alpha = 0, beta = 0;

        for (int k = 1; k < n; k++)
        {

            a = n - (k*(3 * k - 1) / 2);
            b = n - (k*(3 * k + 1) / 2);

            //cout << n << "\t" << k << endl;
            //cout << a << "\t" << b << endl;
            if (a < 0 && b < 0)
                break;


            if (a < 0)
                alpha = 0;

            else if (p[a] != -1)
                alpha = p[a];

            if (b < 0)
                beta = 0;

            else if (p[b] != -1)
                beta = p[b];


            if (p[a] == -1 && p[b] == -1)
            {
                int x = 0, y = 0;
                PartTask& taskA = *new(allocate_child()) PartTask(a, &x);
                PartTask& taskB = *new(allocate_child()) PartTask(b, &y);
                set_ref_count(3);
                spawn(taskA);
                spawn_and_wait_for_all(taskB);
                p[a] = x%5;
                p[b] = y%5;
                alpha = p[a];
                beta = p[b];
            }

            else if (p[a] == -1)
            {
                int x = 0;
                PartTask& taskA = *new(allocate_child()) PartTask(a, &x);
                set_ref_count(2);
                spawn_and_wait_for_all(taskA);
                p[a] = x%5;
                alpha = p[a];
            }

            else if (p[b] == -1)
            {
                int y = 0;
                PartTask& taskB = *new(allocate_child()) PartTask(b, &y);
                set_ref_count(2);
                spawn_and_wait_for_all(taskB);
                p[b] = y%5;
                beta = p[b];
            }
            //cout << "\t" << alpha << "\t" << beta << "\t" << endl;

            if (k % 2 == 0)
                *sum += -1 * (alpha + beta);
            else
                *sum += alpha + beta;

            //cout << *sum << endl;
        }

        if (*sum > 0)
             *sum = *sum%5;
        else
            *sum = 5 + (*sum % 5);

        return NULL;
    }

};




   int main()
   {    
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    vector<int> temp(n,-1);
    p = temp;

    p.at(0) = 1 % 5;
    p.at(1) = 1 % 5;
    p.at(2) = 2 % 5;
    p.at(3) = 3 % 5;
    p.at(4) = 5 % 5;
    p.at(5) = 7 % 5;
    p.at(6) = 11 % 5;

    tick_count parallel_start = tick_count::now();
    task_scheduler_init init;
    int summ = 0;
    PartTask& test = *new(task::allocate_root()) PartTask(n, &summ);
    task::spawn_root_and_wait(test);
    tick_count parallel_end = tick_count::now();
```

Comment: Please disclose PartTask, probably it throws an exception.

Comment: I've added it. As far as I can tell it isnt an issue.

Comment: it works fine in both debug and release modes, the result is summ=2 despite of n value (12, 20000).
I've noticed thread-unsafe usage of std::vector elements: you assign values conditionally depending on previous state. Don't you afraid data races? Are they benign?
What TBB version do you use?

Comment: I'm using the latest TBB build. I've just tried using the TBB concurrent_vector but I am having the same issue. My first attempt used arrays and that gave me the correct results for low n, but as n got high the result would vary.

Comment: concurrent_vector protects concurrent growth, not concurrent accesses. It'll not help you synchronize threads accessing the same element in the vector. So, the program looks ill-formed anyway. Though, I've reproduced the crash on Windows (specific to /GS checks) and answer you soon regarding what's wrong in respect to TBB.

Answer (score 1):

The program is ill-formed for the following reasons which are not connected to TBB itself.

First, it generates accesses to the vector by negative index. It has

```
  if (a < 0 && b < 0)
        break;
```

but in case when only 'a' or only 'b' is negative, it proceeds to p[a] and p[b] accesses. It is the main reason why it fails.

Second, it assigns values to vector element concurrently, it will lead to inconsistent result at least. STL claims thread-safety for std::vector for read-only accesses only. tbb::concurrent_vector does not protects element accesses either. Please use mutex or atomic operations (e.g. `compare_and_swap()`) to protect access to an element.

And the general advice, this low-level blocking-style of TBB programming is neither efficient (because the stack grows) nor readable. I'd recommend using high-level interfaces like `tbb::parallel_invoke()` or `tbb::task_group`

Comment: Thanks I'll look into mutex and atomic operations. However it does not access p[a] and p[b] if a or b are negative. If one is negative and one is positive alpha/beta for the negative will be 0 while the positive will be p[a/b].

Comment: Assigning alpha/beta does not prevent accessing the vector elements in following if's conditions. I've caught "vector subscript out of range" in debugger for `else if (p[b] == -1)`

Comment: Ah I was looking at the wrong bit. I've changed that and I'm using an atomic compare_and_swap but I'm getting the same issue as an array where the answer varies for n > 150.

Comment: atomics can help to only connect condition and write and avoid inconsistent memory state. But if your algorithm writes different value depending on which thread was the first to update it, it is no doubt that the answer may vary and is actually meaningless. There is an error on the algorithmic level then. Ask a separate question: how to parallelize your algorithm correctly providing all the necessary input on what do you want and how does it look in serial form.

Comment: Turns out the issue was that in PartTask I was spawning my tasks in the wrong order. I'm not sure why this is the case, but now it works with arrays as the container.

Comment: Do you mean swap `spawn(taskA)` and `spawn_and_wait_for_all(taskB)`? I don't think it corrects anything, it probably just hides the problem.

Comment: Yes, now even with arrays I'm consistently getting the correct answer. Although I've now changed the %5 to %m where m is a user input and it only gives the corrects results up to m = 5.