# Getting Different Outputs with Recursive, Task-based, Parallel programming in TBB?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, tbb

I'm afraid this is a bit of a long code. I'm programming a parallel, recursive, task-based version of Euler's partition formula with Intel TBB and C++, and I don't *think* there's much problem with this program's logic, but I have a feeling the variables are being accessed wrongly and I might have declared them in the wrong place or something. I say this because inputting a number n should always give the same result, and it does below n = 11, but above that it gives different answers. Even stranger, adding lines of output to try and troubleshoot the program results in slightly more accurate answers (as if somehow padding the time each part of the calculation takes helps it). I have no idea how to avoid this problem or which variable exactly is causing it as the answer is usually fairly close, it's not just a random number. So this is a bit of a tricky one, I apologise, but if someone could help me I would so damn thankful, I've spent a number of hours on this problem.

Here's the parallel task:

```
class ParallelFormula : public task {
public:
int n;
int* pTot;

//Task constructor
ParallelFormula(int n_, int* pTot_) : n(n_), pTot(pTot_) {}

//Task definition
task* execute() {
    //Iterating for formula to work
    for (int k = 1; k > 0; k++) {
        //Add fixed values to pTot for any case where 2 >= n >= 0
        switch (n) {
        case 0:
            if (k % 2 != 0)
                *pTot += 1;
            else
                *pTot -= 1;
            return NULL;
        case 1:
            if (k % 2 != 0)
                *pTot += 1;
            else
                *pTot -= 1;
            return NULL;
        case 2:
            if (k % 2 != 0)
                *pTot += 2;
            else
                *pTot -= 2;
            return NULL;
        }
                    //Calculate p numbers using section of Euler's formula (relies on iteration number)
        p1 = (k*((3 * k) - 1)) / 2;
        p2 = (k*((3 * k) + 1)) / 2;
        if (n >= p2) {
            //If n is more than p2, must call recursive tasks to break down problem to smaller n's, and adds result to total result pTot (i.e. p(n))
            int x = 0;
            int y = 0;
            ParallelFormula& a = *new(allocate_child()) ParallelFormula(n - p1, &x);
            ParallelFormula& b = *new(allocate_child()) ParallelFormula(n - p2, &y);

            //Set ref_count to two children plus one for the wait
            set_ref_count(3);
            //Start b running
            spawn(b);
            //Start a running and wait for all children (a and b)
            spawn_and_wait_for_all(a);
            //Sum the total
            if (k % 2 != 0)
                *pTot += (x + y);
            else
                *pTot -= (x + y);
        }
        else if (n >= p1) {
                            //If n is more than p1, problem is small and therefore need not be parallelised, result added to pTot
            if (k % 2 != 0)
                *pTot += serialLoop(n - p1);
            else
                *pTot -= serialLoop(n - p1);
            return NULL;
        }
        else
            return NULL;
    }
}
};
```

The method that calls the parallel task:

```
int parallelLoop(int n) {
int pTot = 0;
ParallelFormula& a = *new(task::allocate_root()) ParallelFormula(n, &pTot);
task::spawn_root_and_wait(a);
return pTot;
}
```

In case you want to look at the full code for all the context:

```
// Assignment2.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"
#include "tbb/task_scheduler_init.h"
#include "tbb/parallel_reduce.h"
#include "tbb/partitioner.h"
#include "tbb/blocked_range.h"
#include "tbb/tick_count.h"
#include "math.h"

using namespace tbb;
using namespace std;
int p, p1, p2;
int serialLoop(int n);
int n;
int m;

int serialFormula(int pTemp) {
    switch (pTemp) {
    case 0: 
        return 1;
    case 1:
        return 1;
    case 2:
        return 2;
    }
    //If p is any other value it is less than 0 and therefore has nothing to calculate - the current calculation is complete
    return 0;
}

int serialLoop(int n) {
    int pTot = 0;
    for (int k = 1; k > 0; k++) {
        //Checking whether k is even or odd to determine if adding or substracting value of p(x) to make p(n)
        if (n == 0)
            return pTot += 1;
        else if (k % 2 != 0) {
            //Calculate p number using section of Euler's formula
            p = n - ((k*((3 * k) - 1)) / 2);
            //If p is more than 2, must call recursive function to break down problem to smaller n's, and adds result to total result P (i.e. p(n))
            if (p > 2) {
                pTot += serialLoop(p);
            }
            else if (p >= 0) {
                pTot += serialFormula(p);
            }
            else return pTot;

        p = n - ((k*((3 * k) + 1)) / 2);
        if (p > 2) {
            pTot += serialLoop(p);
        }
        else if (p >= 0) {
            pTot += serialFormula(p);
        }
        else return pTot;
    }
    else {
        p = n - ((k*((3 * k) - 1)) / 2);
        if (p > 2) {
            pTot -= serialLoop(p);
        }
        else if (p >= 0) {
            pTot -= serialFormula(p);
        }
        else return pTot;

        p = n - ((k*((3 * k) + 1)) / 2);
        if (p > 2) {
            pTot -= serialLoop(p);
        }
        else if (p >= 0) {
            pTot -= serialFormula(p);
        }
        else return pTot;
    }
}
}

class ParallelFormula : public task {

public:
    int n;
    int* pTot;

//Task constructor
ParallelFormula(int n_, int* pTot_) : n(n_), pTot(pTot_) {}

//Task definition
task* execute() {
    //Checking task is called
    for (int k = 1; k > 0; k++) {
        //Calculate p number using section of Euler's formula
        switch (n) {
        case 0:
            if (k % 2 != 0)
                *pTot += 1;
            else
                *pTot -= 1;
            cout << "Case 0" << endl;
            cout << *pTot << endl;
            return NULL;
        case 1:
            if (k % 2 != 0)
                *pTot += 1;
            else
                *pTot -= 1;
            cout << "Case 1" << endl;
            cout << *pTot << endl;
            return NULL;
        case 2:
            if (k % 2 != 0)
                *pTot += 2;
            else
                *pTot -= 2;
            cout << "Case 2" << endl;
            cout << *pTot << endl;
            return NULL;
        }
        p1 = (k*((3 * k) - 1)) / 2;
        p2 = (k*((3 * k) + 1)) / 2;
        if (n >= p2) {
            //If p is more than 2, must call recursive function to break down problem to smaller n's, and adds result to total result P (i.e. p(n))
            int x = 0;
            int y = 0;
            ParallelFormula& a = *new(allocate_child()) ParallelFormula(n - p1, &x);
            ParallelFormula& b = *new(allocate_child()) ParallelFormula(n - p2, &y);

            //Set ref_count to two children plus one for the wait
            set_ref_count(3);
            //Start b running
            spawn(b);
            //Start a running and wait for all children (a and b)
            spawn_and_wait_for_all(a);
            //Sum the total
            if (k % 2 != 0)
                *pTot += (x + y);
            else
                *pTot -= (x + y);
            cout << "Double p" << endl;
            cout << *pTot << endl;
        }
        else if (n >= p1) {
            if (k % 2 != 0)
                *pTot += serialLoop(n - p1);
            else
                *pTot -= serialLoop(n - p1);
            cout << "Single p" << endl;
            cout << *pTot << endl;
            return NULL;
        }
        else
            return NULL;
    }
}
};

int parallelLoop(int n) {
    int pTot = 0;
    ParallelFormula& a = *new(task::allocate_root()) ParallelFormula(n, &pTot);
    task::spawn_root_and_wait(a);
    return pTot;
}

int main()
{
//Take inputs n and m.
cout << "Enter partition number n:" << endl;
cin >> n;

cout << "Enter modulo m:" << endl;
cin >> m;

//Start timer for serial method
tick_count serial_start = tick_count::now();

//Serial method for computing partition function modulo m.
int sP = serialLoop(n);
int serialMod = sP % m;

//Finish timer for serial method
tick_count serial_end = tick_count::now();

//Output serial results
cout << "Serial result for p(n) is: " << sP << endl;
cout << "Serial result for p(n) mod m is: " << serialMod << endl;
cout << "Serial time (s): " << (serial_end - serial_start).seconds() << endl;

//Start timer for parallel method
tick_count parallel_start = tick_count::now();

//Parallel method for computing partition function
int pP = parallelLoop(n);
int parallelMod = pP % m;

//Finish timer for parallel method
tick_count parallel_end = tick_count::now();

//Output parallel results
cout << "Parallel result for p(n) is: " << pP << endl;
cout << "Parallel result for p(n) mod m is: " << parallelMod << endl;
cout << "Parallel time (s): " << (parallel_end - parallel_start).seconds() << endl;

//Acceleration achieved
cout << "Acceleration achieved was: " << (serial_end - serial_start).seconds() / (parallel_end - parallel_start).seconds() << endl;

return 0;
};
```

P.S. This was partly based off of the Fibonacci sequence example in the Intel TBB documentation, so if I've done something seriously dumb by following that example then I apologise for that too XD.

Comment: *it gives different answers* isn't very useful in diagnosing the problem.  Since you know what the differences are it seems perverse not to share those with us, so share them.  But before you do that, follow the advice given in http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ It (the advice) is most excellent.

Comment: @High Performance Mark: I appreciate that it wasn't a specific question, and that having people debug my programs isn't efficient, but I was at the end of my tether with this particular problem XD. I'll look through the advice and try and action it, thanks for posting it. I have tried breaking the problem down in ways I can actually do and those parts DO work, it seems to be something that happens when the parallel tasks are running, which is something I don't really know how to troubleshoot. So any advice specifically for this area of programming would be helpful too!

Comment: @High Performance Mark Okay, I have a specific question I should've asked before, I get these two warnings:
- warning C4715: 'serialLoop' : not all control paths return a value.
 - warning C4715: 'ParallelFormula::execute' : not all control paths return a value.

I'm not completely sure why these warnings are triggered and I didn't believe the problem I was having was linked as a non-returned value would surely prevent the code from finishing? But I can't see what possible values wouldn't eventually return something, can you?

Comment: Material posted in comments is, by definition, not question material.  If you want to edit your question, then edit it.  If you want to ask a new question, then ask a new question.  The comment box offers too little opportunity for formatting and typography to make 'questions' easy to understand.

Comment: @High Performance Mark: Fair, I think I've figured out that this is all down to my lack of knowledge around pointers, which I just went and looked at properly after the advice suggested so, so thanks for that anyway. For some reason running the code in debug mode got rid of both warnings, I'm still nonplussed as to why that is.

Comment: Please check out the [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23338864/debug-error-when-calling-taskspawn-root-and-wait-in-tbb/23346303#23346303) which debugs the same algorithm

Comment: @Anton That's hilarious, he's my friend in the same class. Thanks for the link :).

Answer (score 1):

The variables `p1` and `p2` are global but you write to them in `ParallelFormula::execute` concurrently. Try to declare them inside the `ParallelFormula::execute` method, e.g.

```
int p1 = (k*((3 * k) - 1)) / 2;
int p2 = (k*((3 * k) + 1)) / 2;
```

Also do not forget about the `p` variable in `int serialLoop(int n)` since you call this function from `ParallelFormula::execute`.

Comment: Thanks Alex, I never managed to get this program working particularly well with Intel TBB, but I've had to remake my solution for this with OpenMP and have done a much better job of it - particularly because it's easier to declare which variables are private or shared between threads and because I devised an iterative solution instead of the recursive mess I made before.